# If the value of this drop down is "1" and the value of this dropdown is " Active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble writing this conditional properly. I want to change it to if the value of #number equals "1" and the value of #status_dropdown equals " Active" then do stuff. This is what I have so far:

```
var status = document.getElementById("status_dropdown").value;

$('#number').on('change', function(){
if ($(this).val() == "1" && (status).val() == " Active") {
  $('div[class*="member-"], .amounts').hide();
    $('.member-1, .donation-0').show();
 } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {  
  $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
    $('.member-2').show();
 } else if ($(this).val() == "3") {  
  $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
    $('.member-3').show();
 } else if ($(this).val() == "0") {  
  $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
 }
});
```

here is the js fiddle with the html with it as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/c11z8xak/

I am not sure how to combine the logical operator with jQuery but open to a straight JS solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the value of the status select on page ready. You've to get the value on the change event too, instead of `(status).val()` use `$("#status_dropdown").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is that you're combining Vanilla JS with jQuery. In the first line, you take status as the value of `#status-dropdown`, which is syntactically fine.

You're then using that value and passing it to jQuery `$(status)`, so it's trying to look for an element with the selector of whatever the value of status is. If you just want a jQuery solution, you can skip the first line and replace `$(status)` with the selector, `$('#status-dropdown')`.

Additionally, you're only checking the value of status once, so your code is checking if the status is active and the value is 1 on the initial conditional, but then it's only checking the value of `$(this)`.

You can either add `&& $('#status-dropdown').val() == "Active")` to each check, or better would be to perform that check first:

```
$('#number').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#status-dropdown').val() === 'Active') {
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $('div[class*="member-"], .amounts').hide();
        $('.member-1, .donation-0').show();
    } else if ($(this).val() === "2") {  
      $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
        $('.member-2').show();
    } else if ($(this).val() === "3") {  
      $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
        $('.member-3').show();
    } else if ($(this).val() === "0") {  
      $('div[class*="member-"]').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Side note: I've changed your `==` to `===` for stronger checking.

Comment: "_The reason this isn't working is that you're combining Vanilla JS with jQuery._" If the value of the selectbox would be a selector that wouldn't be a problem. It's not necessarily bad to combine jQuery with vanilla JS.